# Prove that $\sum_{n \leq z} \frac{\mu(n)^2} { (\mu \star f)(n)} \geq \zeta(2) +O(1/z)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

This question is from Assignment 3 of following notes of Zeev Rudnick:[http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015.html](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015.html)

> Let $f(n)=n^2$. (a) Show that $(f\star \mu)(n)=n^2 \prod_{p|n} (1-\frac{1}{p^2})$

> (b) Show that $\sum_{n \leq z} \frac{\mu(n)^2} { (\mu \star  f)(n)} \geq \zeta(2) +O(1/z)$.

I have done (a). But I am note able make any progress for (b).The LHS of (b) is S(z) in Lecture 10( Selberg Sieve).

Can you please help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\le z}{\mu^2(n)\over(f*\mu)(n)}
&=\sum_{n\le z}{\mu^2(n)\over n^2}\prod_{p|n}{1\over1-p^{-2}}=\sum_{n\le z}\mu^2(n)\prod_{p|n}{p^{-2}\over1-p^{-2}} \\
&=\sum_{n\le z}\mu^2(n)\prod_{p|n}\sum_{r\ge1}{1\over p^{2r}}=\sum_{n\le z}\mu^2(n)\sum_{\substack{m\ge1\\p|m\Rightarrow p|n}}{1\over m^2} \\
&=\sum_{m\ge1}{1\over m^2}\sum_{\substack{n\le z\\p|m\Rightarrow p|n}}\mu^2(n)=\sum_{m\le1}{1\over m^2}|S_{z,m}|
\end{aligned}

where $|S_{z,m}|$ denotes the cardinality of the set

$$
S_{z,m}=\{n\le z:n\text{ squarefree}\wedge p|m\Rightarrow p|n\}
$$

Since $\prod_{p|m}p\in S_{z,m}$ whenever $m\le z$, we conclude the last sum is bounded below by

$$
\sum_{n\le z}{\mu^2(n)\over(f*\mu)(n)}\ge\sum_{m\le z}{1\over m^2}=\zeta(2)+\mathcal O\left(\frac1z\right)
$$

Hope this will address your concern!

Comment: You can verify $(f*\mu)(n)=n^2\prod_{p|n}(1-p^{-2})$ holds whenever $n$ is squarefree.

Comment: how did you wrote $\sum_{n\leq z} \frac{ \mu^2(n)}{n^2} \prod_{p|n} \frac{1}{1- p^{-2}} = $$\sum_{n\leq z} \mu^2 (n) \prod_{p|n} \frac{ p^{-2} }{1 -p^{-2}}?$(1stl ine of your answer)Why is there no $n^2 $on the RHS?

Comment: my question was in the next equality.

Comment: Can you please reply to my comment above?

Comment: Since the $\mu^2(n)$ factor ensures $n$ to be squarefree, which means $n=\prod_{p|n}p$ and $n^2=\prod_{p|n}p^2$.